# Grouping Child nodes under each Parent nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am new to the XSLT grouping concept. I am trying to group the below XML using XSLT 2.0 .

```
<Root>
    <Entry>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>21</Num>
                <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>21</Num>
                <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>        
    </Entry>
</Root>
```

And below is my expected output.

```
<Root>
    <Entry>
        <Split>
            <New_Tag>
                <Data>
                    <Num>20</Num>
                    <Type>A</Type>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Num>20</Num>
                    <Type>A</Type>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Num>20</Num>
                    <Type>A</Type>
                </Data>
            </New_Tag>
            <New_Tag>
                <Data>
                    <Num>20</Num>
                    <Type>B</Type>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Num>20</Num>
                    <Type>B</Type>
                </Data>
            </New_Tag>
        </Split>
        <Split>
            <New_Tag>
                <Data>
                    <Num>21</Num>
                    <Type>A</Type>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Num>21</Num>
                    <Type>A</Type>
                </Data>
            </New_Tag>
        </Split>
    </Entry>
</Root>
```

I want to group 'Data' tags under 'Split'to 'New_Tag' if it has same 'Num' value in XSLT 2.0 . There will be more report entry.
Please help me with this.

Is there ant way to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the `Split` elements by `Data/Num` and rename the `Split`'s
to `New_Tag`.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<Root>
    <Entry>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>20</Num>
                <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>
        <Split>
            <Data>
                <Num>21</Num>
                <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Num>21</Num>
                <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
        </Split>        
    </Entry>
</Root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Split" group-by="Data/Num">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Split">
    <New_Tag>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </New_Tag>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Root>
   <Entry>
      <Split>
         <New_Tag>
            <Data>
               <Num>20</Num>
               <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
               <Num>20</Num>
               <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
               <Num>20</Num>
               <Type>A</Type>
            </Data>
         </New_Tag>
         <New_Tag>
            <Data>
               <Num>20</Num>
               <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
               <Num>20</Num>
               <Type>B</Type>
            </Data>
         </New_Tag>
      </Split>
      <Split>
         <New_Tag>
            <Data>
               <Num>21</Num>
               <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data>
               <Num>21</Num>
               <Type>C</Type>
            </Data>
         </New_Tag>
      </Split>
   </Entry>
</Root>
```